# Plotting with ggplot2 a non linear regression obtained with NLS

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls

I am trying to interpolate with ggplot2 an interpolated function and overlap it to the dotplot graph of the single values.

I obtain an error that I am not able to understand, like if I were binding two different vectors of different length.

```
3: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 80, 6
```

The complete code is written below:

```
library(ggplot2)

tabella <- data.frame("Tempo" = c(0, 15, 30, 60, 90, 120), "Visc" = c(500, 9125, 11250, 10875, 11325, 10375))
attach(tabella)

Visc.mod <- nls((Visc ~ 500 + (k1*Tempo/(k2+Tempo))), start=list(k1=100, k2=100), trace=TRUE)
cor(Visc,predict(Visc.mod))
predict(Visc.mod)
summary(Visc.mod)



ggplot(tabella, aes(x=Tempo, y=Visc)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = "nls", 
              method.args = list(formula = "Visc ~ 500 + (k1*Tempo/(k2+Tempo))",
              start = list(k1=100, k2=100)), data = tabella, se = FALSE)
```

I really do not understand where the mistake could be.

Thank you in advance for every reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to run without errors by moving the formula argument. However the fit doesn't look particularly good though.

```r
library(ggplot2)

tabella <- data.frame("Tempo" = c(0, 15, 30, 60, 90, 120), "Visc" = c(500, 9125, 11250, 10875, 11325, 10375))

ggplot(tabella, aes(x=Tempo, y=Visc)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y ~ 500 + (k1 * x / (k2 + x)),
              method.args = list(start = list(k1=100, k2=100)), data = tabella, se = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One issue with your code is that the formula is a parameter of nls and you need to pass a formula object to it and not a character.
Secondly, ggplot2 passes `y` and `x` to nls and not `Visc` and `Tempo`

```
ggplot(tabella, aes(x = Tempo, y = Visc)) +
geom_point()+
geom_smooth(
method = "nls",
formula = y ~ 500 + (k1 * x / (k2 + x)),
method.args = list(start = c(k1 = 100, k2 = 100)),
se=FALSE)
```

I was typing my answer when @teunbrand preceded me. However, I place it using `geom_smooth` instead of `stat_smooth`
Same result. Not a good fit[image]

Comment: Thank you both for your answer. I understoofd the mistake. The fit is not good because i put two random values as starting values. Changing them with more accuracy the result is much better.

`ggplot(tabella, aes(x=Tempo, y=Visc)) +   geom_point() +   stat_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y ~ 500 + (k1 * x / (k2 + x)), method.args = list(start = list(k1=12000, k2=2.5)), data = tabella, se = FALSE)`